# Can i use Local ICE Candidates as indications of connectivity?

Tags: webrtc

My task is to determine the connectivity of a single browser client. I was wondering if the emitted Local ICE Candidates are any indication to the client's connectivity. So examining a candidate originating from google's STUN server:

```
mid: audio, candidate: a=candidate:941443129 2 udp 1845501695 2.84.19.92 49669 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.2 rport 49669 generation 0
```

I can see my public ip `2.84.19.32` and i can also view my local, behind the NAT, ip `192.168.1.2`. At this point i also know that the browser is listening on UDP port 49669 and waiting for connections. Can i infer at this point that the STUN client has made a successful connection to my public ip and port?

I understand it is ICE's job to determine if a connection is possible to that Candidate, but is it possible to determine connectivity with a single client (browser)?

My ultimate question / task, is to tap into the ICE process and know for a fact if the [single] client is behind a NAT and what type of NAT that is. Is that possible?

Comment: You can determine what kind of ice candidate it is by looking at 'typ' attribute, if it is 'host' then it is definitely behind the NAT, when it is 'relay' then it is outside the NAT.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of candidates doesn't give the information that you have connectivity. But if you analyze the content of them, you can conclude some things.
You need to take into account what STUN/TURN servers you are using.

- If nothing is defined you can still have candidates, if the device is connected in a network and has an IP attributed (even if the network has no access to the Internet), you will only have candidates with local IP address.
- If you define a server, and you get candidates with other types than host, it means that you have connection (at least connection to the defined STUN/TURN server, that is supposed to be outside of your machine).

To know if you are behind a NAT, you can check the presence of host candidates with local IP's.

After you get a candidate, it means that that host:ip is accessible from the internet. That's the whole idea of contacting a external STUN/TURN server. Is to open that ports... But, the fact that they are accessible, doesn't mean that you will receive attacks. You can in fact receive, but that is where the key negotiation enters and checks that only other peer (the ones with the keys) can "establish a connection" to that host:port

Comment: But does getting an ICE candidate from an external STUN server (i.e. google's) means that my host is accessible from the internet on the host:ip provided by the new Candidate? It is my understanding that STUN/TURN have nothing to do with connectivity, they will just provide me with what my IP address is as the STUN server sees it and a relay server in case a TURN server has been defined...

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer to the question "Can i determine connectivity by reading Candidates emission by ICE", the answer as @nakib said is "no".

Comment: Exactly. If you define a STUN server and you get a candidate from it, it means that you have connection to the network (as I said, at least connection to that server). And that means that your host:ip is accessible from the internet. That's the whole idea of contacting a external server. Is to open that ports... But, the fact that they are accessible, doesn't mean that you will receive attacks. You can in fact receive, but that is where the key negotiation enters and checks that only other peer can "establish a connection" to that host:port

Comment: I just verified that ICE candidates do actually report on connectivity, if you receive a HOST candidate it means that the STUN server can connect at that address/port/proto. This discovery has been applied to www.check-connectivity.com so it will reliably determine if you accept incoming UDP/TCP connections

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get this data out of the webRTC connection object:

```
pc.iceConnectionState, this tells you the connection process
pc.iceGatheringState, this is about the 'getting' of the ice candidates
```

But both don't really seem to work, as I am behind a firewall which blocks the RTC, but `pc.iceConnectionState` still gives me connected, but you might give it a go and see if it works for you.